# Combinatorial Group Theory / Lyndon & Schupp, Proposition 4.1.. Automorphisms of free groups

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I have problem to understand the three final lines of the proof of the proposition 4.1 in page 23.
The proposition is a generalization of the fact that $Aut(F_{n})$ is f.g.
It says that if $F$ is a free group with basis X and $Aut_{f}(F)$ is the group that is generated by the elementary Nielsen transformations $a_{x} $ and $b_{xy}$, then for every $ u_{1}, .... u_{n} \in F $ and $a \in Aut_{f}(F)$ there is a $b \in Aut_{f}(F)$ such that $ u_{j} a = u_{j} b $ for every j.
The proof starts supposing that X is infinite $X = (x_{1}, x_{2},..)$ finds a $Y= (x_{1}, ..., x_{p})$  finite such that $u_{1}, .... u_{n} \in Gp Y$ and a Z such that $Y \subseteq Gp Za^{-1}$ and we suppose that $Y \subseteq Z = (x_{1},..., x_{q}), p \le q $.

If $U = Za^{-1} = (u_{1}, ..., u_{n})$ and then there is a Nielsen transformation b such that $bU = V$ which is Nielsen reduced. Using a lemma can suppose that $V = (x_{1}, ... x_{p}, v_{p+1}, ..., v_{q})$ for some $v_{j}$. So we have that $V = bU = bZa^{-1}$.

Then uses that Z is initial segment of X and concludes that V is initial component of length q of $bXa^{-1}$. Then says that the fact that X is the matrix of the identity automorphism, implies the equation below.

I can't understand the equation $bXa^{-1}$ = $ba^{-1}$. I have a problem with notation because the book uses a notation of matrices for endomorphisms of free groups and I am not sure this means and how it is implied by the fact that $ X$ is the matrix of the identity automorphism.

About the notation: If we have an endomorphism f of the free group $F$ with basis X then we associate as matrix the ordered set $U = (u_{1}, u_{2} ..., ), u_{i}= x_{i}f $ viewed as words in $X$

Comment: I don't have the book. :-(

Comment: Please include the content of the proof which you are confused about.  It would be unwise to assume that anyone here has the same book (and edition) as you do.

Comment: He explains this carefully in the second complete paragraph of page 22, so you really need to understand that. The point is that, if you apply the automorphism $\alpha^{-1}$ to the basis $X$ and then apply the Nielsen transformation $\beta$ to the resulting words, then the effect on $X$ is the same as the composite automorphism $\beta \alpha^{-1}$ (where $\beta$ comes first). I would advise ignoring the references to matrices. They are just put in to provide an analogy with elementary operations in linear algebra, which may or may not be helpful.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you make that an answer?